# Cannot get Google Places Atmosphere Data

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

[image: Places Api]

[image: PostMan Image]

I enabled Places Api and i am trying to fetch place Atmosphere Data but i cannot get Atmosphere Data.

Comment: Any reason why my question is marked with -1?

Comment: Can you please post (as code / URL) the full API request you're making (excluding your own API key)?

Answer (score 0):

Everything was correct it was delay from Google server anybody having issues in this can ask me.